# TFS 2015 getting the global list with JavaScript for extension

Tags: javascript, tfs, global

We have a TFS extension created, but we would like to be able to get items from our global list to use to populate a drop down field.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  If it is can you provide a snippet of example code with how to access and get values from the global list using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can all [exportWorkItemTypeDefinition()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2#exportWorkItemTypeDefinition) method in your extension to get this information.

There are three parameters for this method:

> - project: string. Optional. Project ID or project name
> - type: string. Optional.
> - exportGlobalLists: boolean. Optional.

Specifying "project" and "type" to "null" and "exportGlobalLists" to "true", you will get the global workflow exported with global lists included in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the global lists via TFS API [ExportGlobalLists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.exportgloballists.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). However, it's not support with JavaScript.

You can also use the ***witadmin*** command-line tool to achieve

*Display the names of global lists*

```
witadmin listgloballist /collection:http://AdventureWorksServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

*Export the definition of global lists*

```
witadmin exportgloballist /collection:http://AdventureWorksServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /f:C:mygloballists
```

Source Link: [Manage global lists for work item types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.exportgloballists.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

*Note:* To access the witadmin command-line tool, seems you can only open a Command Prompt window where either you’ve installed a version of Visual Studio and enter: `cd %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

Answer (score 0):

I used the TFS Work Item Tracking rest client (which I have in the variable restClient) in the following JavaScript code to get the global list:

```
restClient.exportWorkItemTypeDefinition("myProject", null, true).then(function(xml) {
   //xml is now a string that I can parse and use as I need 
});
```

A link to documentation on TFS WorkItemTrack API I found in case anyone else also finds it useful: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2